# RAM memory usage and management: R vs Power BI. Why Power Bi seems to deal better with large datasets than R in the same computer?

Tags: r, powerbi, ram

This is more of a hardware-related question. In my company we work with both R (for data analysis) and Power BI (for data visualization). We have an asset build in R to perform domain specific calculations and we display the output in PowerBI with some more or less complex graphs and calculated fields.

We recently had to deal with a dataset of 2Gb/7 million records with our PCs (HP 830 G5 - i58250U - 8Gb RAM). R timed out during our calculations with the above dataset while Power BI was able to handle it relatively easily.

I know R actively uses RAM memory as temporary storage of objects, and that might have been a problem. But why it was not a problem with Power BI? The reason I am asking this is to figure out whether just buying/installing more RAM in our all laptops is a good solution. We need both R and Power BI for our asset to work.

Thank you very much!

Comment: It is impossible to answer this question without knowing more specifics. My first guess would be inefficient programming on the R side. A 2gb dataset should be easy to handle with that PC. First suggestion: take a look at data.table instead of any tidyverse packages, if you are doing any heavy data manipulation. Java heapsize and garbage collection might also be terms you should look for, but without more spefics, it'll be hard.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Let's say the dataset would be bigger, e.g. 10Gb. If objects' size R is generating surpasses the available RAM, it does not matter the programming efficiency, it will time out. Right? An alternative solution would be to redo all the code to analyze data in bits (i.e. reduce the object size), but this is not an ideal solution for us given the amount of work needed. So why PowerBI desktop seems to handle well files of any size? How is it using the RAM in our PCs?

Comment: Power BI uses a in memory compression engine called veritpaq, that compresses data on row and column, and is split into a storage and calculation parts, that may explain some of the efficiency in ram usage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No amount of RAM will make up for efficient code. Throwing hardware at a software problem might help initially, but won't scale as well as good code. Without knowing more about your particular usecase, the best advice I can give is to utilize more efficient libraries such as `data.table`, or one of the other efficient solutions highlighted in [this piece](https://csgillespie.github.io/efficientR/).

You should also consider working in [parallell](https://nceas.github.io/oss-lessons/parallel-computing-in-r/parallel-computing-in-r.html), utilizing more than one core for your instance. Power BI might to this automatically, but in R you will have to explicitly state so.

With files less than 10 GB, R should have no problem. However, above 10 GB requires some workaround, as highlighted in this [article](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/72295_692737b667614d369bd87cb0f51c9a4b.html).